# Pandas groups() method not returning the group names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Created a pandas dataframe and tried to group using a column name. The grouping does happen but for some reason its not giving the group names when I am trying to get it using groups() method. It returns "TypeError: 'PrettyDict' object is not callable". This method used to work earlier and used to return the group names but for some reason its not working anymore. Am i missing anything. The pandas version and python version are mentioned below. Can someone please help in narrowing down the issue.

```
>>> data = {'Hemisphere' : ["Northern", "Northern", "Northern", "Southern", "Southern",], 'Country' : ['India', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Australia', 'New Zealand']}
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  Hemisphere      Country
0   Northern        India
1   Northern          USA
2   Northern       Canada
3   Southern    Australia
4   Southern  New Zealand
>>> a=df.groupby("Hemisphere")
>>> a.groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PrettyDict' object is not callable
>>> ^D
(orgvenv-v2) pradeep@Pradeeps-MacBook-Pro org-structure % pip freeze
numpy==1.21.4
pandas==1.3.4
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
(orgvenv-v2) pradeep@Pradeeps-MacBook-Pro org-structure % python 
Python 3.8.6 (v3.8.6:db455296be, Sep 23 2020, 13:31:39) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: Works for me with `a.groups`.  Note, no brackets or parentheses after `groups`.

Comment: Thanks a ton... get_group() is a method and groups is a dict. I thought both are methods.

Comment: Happy to help.  Obviously I've had more than enough experience with messages of the form `... is not callable`.